# Creating a selection set from selected features using select by location

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, select, vb.net

I am trying to convert my VBA code to vb.net. I use “Select by location” to select all the points that intersect lines. Then I want to click a button to put the points into a selection set. Then I can use two other buttons to cycle through the selection set.

When I try to convert my code I keep on getting the following error in vb.net.:

In vb I keep on getting error for ‘pFeatureCursor’ saying “Variable ‘pFeatureCursor’ is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Public Sub GetSelSet()
  Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
  Dim pMap As IMap
  Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
  Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
  Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
  Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
  Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
  Dim pCurFeat As IFeature
  Dim intLayer As Integer

  Set pMxDoc = Application.Document
  Set pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
  Set pActiveView = pMap
  Set pSelSet = New esriSystem.Set
  CurrentIndex = 0

  For intLayer = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1
    If TypeOf pMap.Layer(intLayer) Is IFeatureLayer Then
      Set pFeatureLayer = pMap.Layer(intLayer)
      If Not pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass Is Nothing Then
        If pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.featureCount(Nothing) > 0 Then
          Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer
          Set pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet
          pSelectionSet.Search Nothing, False, pFeatureCursor
          Set pCurFeat = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
  
          Do While Not pCurFeat Is Nothing
            pSelSet.Add pCurFeat
            Set pCurFeat = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
          Loop
  
        End If
      End If
    End If

  Next intLayer

End Sub
```

Comment: You say the error is occurring in your VB .Net code but you have uploaded your VBA code which I assume is the code you are trying to convert, may be you should show the code that is actually causing the error message to occur?

Comment: Also is this actually an error and not a  WARNING given by visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning and not an error, the compiler is making you aware that there's a trap you might hit.. however you've got quite a few lines of code to enumerate the feature selection from IMap.Layers which *will not traverse group layers* - that's a more serious concern, if a layer isn't valid (red exclamation mark indicating the data isn't found) your code will crash and burn!

Rather than walking down that stony path IMap implements [FeatureSelection](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//001200000m9n000000) which does ignore invalid layers and find selection in group layers (this is VB.net code, you'll need to add SET keyword when assigning objects):

```
Dim pCnt As Long
Dim pSelection As IEnumFeature
Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
pSelSet = New esriSystem.Set

pMap = pDoc.FocusMap 'pMap is of type IMap and pDoc is IMxDocument
If pMap.SelectionCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

' pMap.FeatureSelection is of type ISelection wich is implemented by EnumFeature
pSelection = CType(pMap.FeatureSelection, IEnumFeature)
pMaxFeat = pMap.SelectionCount

For pCnt = 0 To pMaxFeat - 1
    pSelSet.Add pSelection.Next
Next
```

Will get you to the same goal in less lines with an added layer of safety; note that in the selection set features will derive from different feature classes, use [IFeature.Class as IFeatureClass](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//00250000062r000000) to locate the source for each feature. This code can easily be converted to use [IEditor.EditSelection](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//0020000000s8000000) to find all the features that are selected *and editable* implemented as IEnumFeature.

I hope that helps.